# NSDecimalNumber from NSString not equal?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I've got the weirdest thing happening.

Code:

```
NSString *input = @"357835487953487345879345897345897345897534";
NSLog(@"%@", input);
NSDecimalNumber *number = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:input];
NSLog(@"%@", number);
```

Output:

```
 357835487953487345879345897345897345897534
 357835487953487345879345897345897345890000
```

So the number's aren't the same, I it has something to do with the accuracy of floating point numbers. So what can I do to get these to be equal? Why is it replacing the last few digits with zero?

Answer (score 4):

Check the documentation for [NSDecimalNumber](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> NSDecimalNumber, an immutable subclass of NSNumber, provides an object-oriented wrapper for doing base-10 arithmetic. An instance can represent any number that can be expressed as mantissa x 10^exponent where mantissa is a decimal integer up to 38 digits long, and exponent is an integer from –128 through 127.

When I run your code they are the same until the 38th digit:

357835487953487345879345897345897345897534
357835487953487345879345897345897345890000

Answer (score 3):

It is replacing the end of your number by zeroes because an NSDecimal number is limited in precision… all numbers are. So internally,

`357835487953487345879345897345897345897534`

is stored as

`35783548795348734587934589734589734589 * 1E4`

You will not have this issue with a *shorter* number (i.e. a number with less sygnificant digits).

From the docs:

> NSDecimalNumber, an immutable subclass of NSNumber, provides an
>   object-oriented wrapper for doing base-10 arithmetic. An instance can
>   represent any number that can be expressed as mantissa x 10^exponent
>   where mantissa is a decimal integer up to 38 digits long, and exponent
>   is an integer from –128 through 127.

In short, you may need other storage solutions to hold numbers with more sygnificant digits (digits others than zeroes).

You may want to look for [arbitrary precision arithmetics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic). Take a look at: [GMP](http://gmplib.org). Maybe it can help you.

Comment: Well, I guess that answers my question. I'm trying to get this string into a number that I can do math on (to convert it to hex) but I don't think any variables are big enough...

Comment: No, this is the max you can get using standard variables… You may want to look for arbitrary precision arithmetics. Take a look at: http://gmplib.org